# How to place a rectangular image background to a button in Android?

Tags: android, image

I am working on an Android GUI, and I want to place some **buttons with image backgrounds** on a vertical linear layout. I designed button graphics and saved it in .png format. Then, I created a new Android Icon set which will be later related with a button or an imagebutton view.

[image]

I can only select "launcher icon" because notification, actionbar, menu type of icons are not suitable (they are not color at first).

When I select "Center" option, my button images do not fully cover the button area. So I cannot align button images appropriately. When I select "crop" option, my button image is cropped and is no longer a rounded rectangle as I desire.

[image: The image in bottom is croped, the others are centered]

What can I do? Thanks for your patience in reading, it may be longer than necessary.

Comment: So you need **9 patches**... rename your imag extensions to  **.9.png**, not just .png. Then add a 1 px **transparent** border per side. and use **pure black** to mark the stretchable areas/content areas (top and left/bottom and rigth, respectively). Here's a nice tutorial: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I will examine it today, it looks like what I was looking for.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of 9 patches. You'll see how powerful these objects are. And they are also easy to master!